# CSV to notepad changes the decimal places

Tags: notepad

When I converted a file from CSV to notepad, the number of decimal places in the notepad changes to 4 decimal places. How can change this so that notepad can read the exact number of decimal places from CSV.
For example, I have 0.0000005 in my CSV file, but when I convert it to notepad, I now have 0.0000

Hence my number has been changed from 0.0000005 to 0.0000

How can I prevent this from happening. Note that I have the cells wide enough to be able to see the  numbers in the CSV but it never exports properly to notepad.
Thanks for your anticipated help.

Comment: A CSV file is already a textfile and doesn't need to be converted to "notepad" - I don't even know what you're doing here, but it seems weird to me. Just leave the file as it is?

Comment: my question is why in notepad the precision is different? The application that I am using is giving an error because of this issue

Comment: Notepad is just a text editor, it doesn't do anything like that. So are we talking about the same notepad? Because the tag you used refers to Windows' default text editor.

Comment: let me rephrase it. I made a mistake to mention that it was a CSV. It is actually an excel workbook with VBA that writes to notepad. Notepad then keeps the numbers to only 4 decimal places. Any ideas on how I can correct this?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I found the setting in my excel that caused this issue